# OrgMode, How to make references to chapter/section name?

Tags: org-mode

Say my part of document is like:

```
* My Chapter
  
  ......

** My Section

  ......
```

I want to use the words "My Chapter", inside the "My Section" area. Instead of copying the literal "My Chapter", I want to **reference** it, like a variable, so that in the future, when compiling it from *.org* to *.txt* by using *Org Export*, I don't need to modify the document if "My Chapter" is changed to "My New Chapter", it'd be something like this:

```
* My Chapter
  
  ......

** My Section

  This is a section named ${section_name} from a chapter named ${chapter_name}
```

My Q is: ***Is possible to do it in Orgmode?***

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/16355768/18118915 and https://orgmode.org/manual/Internal-Links.html

Comment: @TianshuWang  thanks for the links, but I am looking for the one that without needs to predefine the anchor point, that is, put a placeholder next to the Section before I can reference it. And in addition, using Internal Links seems no help for obtaining a literal Section Name directly.

Comment: Oh, I see, I misunderstand your question.

Comment: It is not clear from your question in what context you want the placeholders replaced. Are you asking about replacing them during export (in which case @dalanicolai's answer does the job)? Or do you have something else in mind? E.g. "I want to see the buffer in emacs with the values overlaid on the placeholders" might be a different interpretation. Please edit your question and clarify the context in which you want this replacement to happen.

Comment: @NickD Thanks for pointing out that, I have refined the question and make it more clear.

Comment: Thanks - that clarifies the question and makes it clear that the answer addresses the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be achieved by defining macro templates. You can either define them locally or globally as explained in the [Macro Replacement section of the Org manual](https://orgmode.org/manual/Macro-Replacement.html).

You can set them globally using the following code snippet (which seems to me what you want):

```lisp
(setq org-export-global-macros
      '((section-name . "(eval (car (org-get-outline-path t)))")
        (subsection-name . "(eval (car (last (org-get-outline-path t))))")))
```

Now you can use them as follows

```
* My name is Section
** My name is Subsection
This is section '{{{section-name}}}' and subsection '{{{subsection-name}}}'
```

Comment: Thanks, That's it!  the awesome 3-line elisp, seems like a magic to me!